# How to include multiple JavaScript libs in PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS to generate a series of images based on the state of an HTML canvas element which I am manipulating via JS. This canvas manipulation depends on 3 separate JS libraries and some inline scripts which I invoke during `window.onload`.

The [PhantomJS docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/include-js.html) cover how to include a single JS library, but it doesn't cover how to include several.

Can anyone provide me with the correct syntax to include several JS libs, and then run some scripts during `window.onload`?

Comment: For the time being I am concatenating all my JS dependencies into a single file to get around this, but I'd rather not if a proper solution is available.

Answer (score 5):

There is a callback for `page.includeJs()`. When the first one is done, then you can load the next one. This is usually done recursively.

```
function multipleIncludeJs(page, jsArray, done) {
    if (jsArray.length === 0) {
        done();
        return;
    }

    var url = jsArray.shift();
    page.includeJs(url, function(){
        multipleIncludeJs(page, jsArray, done);
    });
}
```

and use it like this:

```
multipleIncludeJs(page, ["http://code.jquery...", "http://getbootstrap..."], function(){
    console.log("loaded");
});
```